# xml.dom.minidom count how many tags of a specific type exist

Tags: python, xml, xmldom

I'm trying to work with the wolfram alpha api and I want to get a count back of how many `<plaintext></plaintext>` elements there are so I can run through them with dom.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use,

```
dom.getElementsByTagName("plaintext").length
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList which has a property `length`.

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#nodelist-objects)